# using return inside loop and method

Tags: java, while-loop, return

I am trying to return the value of the method but the loop is throwing an error because the return has to be in the method body not in the loop. I am using system.out.println and it is works but I want to use return instead.

```
package AnimeAid;

import java.io.*;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;

public class ReadFile {


    public void getFileInformation() throws IOException {   
        try{
            String file;
            file = "tra.srt";
            Charset charset = Charset.defaultCharset();
            Path path = Paths.get(file);
            BufferedReader reader = Files.newBufferedReader(path, charset);
            System.out.printf("Lines from %s:%n",file);
            String line;

            while((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                if (line.indexOf(':') != -1 && line.indexOf(',') != -1 && line.indexOf('0') != -1) { 
                    System.out.println(line.substring(0, 12)); 
                }
            }
        }catch(FileNotFoundException ex){
            System.err.println(ex);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: please describe what you are trying to do with this code.

Comment: ok i will give me some time

Comment: you can take a look i changed it all

Comment: A return statement can be in a loop (of course it will be executed at most once). The problem here seems to be that the method is declared as `void`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can obviously return from the for loop.

```
public String getFileInformation() throws IOException {   
 try{
    String file;
    file = "tra.srt";
    Charset charset = Charset.defaultCharset();
    Path path = Paths.get(file);
    BufferedReader reader = Files.newBufferedReader(path, charset);
    System.out.printf("Lines from %s:%n",file);
    String line;

    while((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    if (line.indexOf(':') != -1 && line.indexOf(',') != -1 && line.indexOf('0') != -1) { 
    return line.substring(0, 12); 
    }
    }
    }catch(FileNotFoundException ex){
    System.err.println(ex);
    }

    return "";
}
```

Comment: return are not used for printing right ? so nothing going to show up ?

Comment: but you said you want to return value?

Comment: that is right i set your answer as right answer but i am asking about return function

Comment: Sorry but i didn't get you. Can you please say clearly what you actually want? Then I may help you further.